# Allow user to sign in with Facebook, Twitter, Gmail Account in android app

Tags: android, android-facebook, android-twitter, android-authenticator

I want my app to have Sign In with Facebook or Twitter or Gmail. My app will not post on theire respective account, just a way of authorization or user creation for my app.

Is there any easy library to achieve that without hustle of SDKs or complex configuration.

Any suggestions or examples will be very much helpful.

Comment: Facebook has a good example: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

Comment: please read the FAQ - and then realize that the way to solve your problem is to investigate, then implement, the debug, then ask for help showing relevant code.  IOW, the purpose of SO is not to do your research for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) library. It allows you to implement numerous social networking sites using one simple library.

> The API enables user authentication and sharing updates through
>   different various social networks and hides all the intricacies of
>   generating signatures & token, doing security handshakes and provide
>   an easy mechanism to build cool social apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try [socialAuth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/). It is for android. It is a open source too.